# What is default jvm error log location?

Tags: java

If an error log location isn't specified when executing `java -cp ../blah someplace/somejar.jar` where would the jvm error log be written to?

Comment: The default location for files is your working directory.

Comment: Console if its System.err or System.out, if its some kind of logging framework the answer would be "depending on the framework" :)

Comment: If your using a Mac, try searching for `Console` in spotlight (the magnifier in your top-right corner). That shows most errors that are written to something else than the terminal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What do you mean by "jvm error"? If you refer to stack-traces, these are written to `System.err` which leads to the `standard error stream`. This is typically printed in your terminal, just as `System.out` is. You can redirect this if you want, either when calling the JVM (using `2> /my/file.log`) or from within your code by redirecting `System.err`.

Some logging frameworks redirect the std-error, then it depends on your configuration.

If you refer to JVM Crash logs (which are created if the JVM crashes, which should never happen if you do not use JNI, but in fact they sometimes occur) the situation is different. These are typically created in the folder where the jvm was launched. If this folder is not writable, the `/tmp` directory is used on Unix-Systems.

Comment: Well, again, if you do not use a logging-framework then yes. If you use one, check its configuration.

Comment: `If you refer to JVM Crash logs (which are created if the JVM crashes, which should never happen if you do not use JNI)`

This is exactly my case, but can't find the crash log anywhere, can you please help me figuring out how to get it?

Answer (score 6):

According to [Java Platform, Standard Edition Troubleshooting Guide: Location of Fatal Error Log](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/felog001.html), the system attempts to create the file **in the working directory of the process** if the `-XX:ErrorFile=file` flag is not specified.

In the event that the file cannot be created in the working directory (insufficient space, permission problem, or other issue), the file is created in the temporary directory for the operating system.

- On **Oracle Solaris** and **Linux** operating systems the temporary directory is `/tmp`.
- On **Windows** the temporary directory is specified by the value of the `TMP` environment variable; if that environment variable is not defined, the value of the `TEMP` environment variable is used.