# JavaFx - Default location for logs and configuration files

Tags: javafx

From a JavaFX application, on Windows 10/11 and Os X, I need to read configuration files and write log files. What is the default location for each platform. Is it the user home folder?

```
String homeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
```

Or some preference folder? What is best practice?

Is this the correct approach to read/store information...

```
    String appName = "AppName";
    String localDataFolderPath = "";

    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");

    if(osName.contains("Mac")){
        localDataFolderPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/Preferences/" + appName + "/";
    }else{
        localDataFolderPath = System.getenv("APPDATA") + "\\Local\\" + appName + "\\";
    }
```

Comment: I initialize from `java.util.Properties` resources  and use `java.util.prefs.Preferences` to store local changes; see also [_What is default jvm error log location?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14102293/230513)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Recommended Approach (My Opinion)**

I create a directory `.<appname>` under the system `user.home` directory, like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72294934/how-to-save-a-file-uploaded-by-filechooser-to-a-directory-in-your-project/72311598#72311598).  For me that is simple and portable across different environments.  It may not be optimal or standard for each environment, but is not uncommon for a lot of apps.

[java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.htmlhttps://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html) defines a common storage format and access interface for configuration information.

**Alternates (if the suggested user directory based configuration is insufficient)**

Some alternate approaches are [`java.util.prefs.Preferences`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.prefs/java/util/prefs/package-summary.html) as noted by Trashgod in comments, which can optionally be combined with [letting the user choose where to store stuff](https://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-tutorial/part5/).

**Spring Config**

Frameworks like Spring will use [configuration properties](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) and have their own system for looking up and finding those properties (which can be quite complex).  Generally for Spring, default configuration values will be pre-configured in resources and can be overridden by custom values in a local property file as needed.  If using Spring, refer to the Spring configuration documentation for their recommendations for best practices for configuration management.

**User Settings vs Application Config**

You may have different configuration for the application, versus custom configurations for individual users.  In which case you might wish to place a config directory under your application install (e.g. for a jlink or jpackage install, also create a config directory in the generated image, using those tools) and perhaps also adopt the user directory based configuration or user preferences based configuration for user config.  How to do that is out of scope for this answer, refer to the jlink or package documentation for more info.

**Initializing config from defaults**

To setup initial property defaults, you might use a scheme such as that proposed by James answer to:

- [Copy external resource files after building JavaFX app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73928189/1155209).